# NSDate Units and Calculations

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm working on a project that needs to check the time difference from a first launch date. I'm using the NSDayCalendarUnit and NSWeekCalendarUnit. Basically for the first 2 weeks on every second day I want to perform something. The object I'm using needs to be in a certain state for each two days at a time.

So for example

```
Day 1 & 2, Week 0 - State 1
Day 3 & 4, Week 0 - State 2
...
Day 1 & 2, Week 1 - State 8
Day 3 & 4, Week 1 - State 9
```

Here is my code:

```
    // get the data/time difference from the first launch
    int daysDifferent = [[dateDifferenceInfo objectForKey:@"days"] intValue];
    int weeksDifferent = [[dateDifferenceInfo objectForKey:@"weeks"] intValue];

    if(daysDifferent == 2 | daysDifferent == 3 && !weeksDifferent && _dot.age != 2){
        // set state
    }

    if(daysDifferent == 4 | daysDifferent == 5 && !weeksDifferent && _dot.age != 3){
        // set state
    }
    if((daysDifferent == 6 && weeksDifferent == 0 | daysDifferent == 0 && weeksDifferent == 1) && _dot.age != 4){
       // set state
    }

    if(daysDifferent == 0 | daysDifferent == 1 && weeksDifferent == 1 && _dot.age != 5){
       // set state
    }

    if(daysDifferent == 2 | daysDifferent == 3 && weeksDifferent == 1  && _dot.age != 6){
      // set state   
    }

    if(daysDifferent == 4| daysDifferent == 5 && weeksDifferent == 1  && _dot.age != 7){
      // set state   
    }

    if((daysDifferent == 6 && weeksDifferent == 1 | daysDifferent == 0 && weeksDifferent == 2)  && _dot.age != 8){
      // set state
    }

    if(weeksDifferent >= 2 && !(daysDifferent % 2)){
      // set state
    }
```

Side note: I know it's bad code, I plan to replace this with switch cases, I just need to logic sorted first.

My question is is there a better way of calculating this kind of pattern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not totally clear on your goal, as you say:

> for the first 2 weeks on every second day I want to perform something.
>
> So for example

```
Day 1 & 2, Week 0 - State 1
Day 3 & 4, Week 0 - State 2
...
Day 1 & 2, Week 1 - State 8
Day 3 & 4, Week 1 - State 9
```

Where I would have thought it would be

```
Day 1 & 2, Week 0 - State 1
Day 3 & 4, Week 0 - State 2
Day 5 & 6, Week 0 - State 3
Day 7 Week 0 & Day 1 Week 1 - State 4.
...
```

So if your example is right, the calculation is different.

Based on the simpler example, I would calculate the time interval since the first date, and divide by twice the length of a day, taking the floor.  That is the state:

```
NSDate *firstDate = ...
NSDate *secondDate = ...
NSTimeInterval interval = [ secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate: firstDate ];
double secondsPerDay = 60 * 60 * 24.0; // s per min times min per hr times hrs per dy. 
int state = (int) (interval / secondsPerDay * 0.5 ) + 1;
```

If, on the other hand, it really is as you have described, the approach I would use as fast and simple would be to do a similar calculation - leaving out the 0.5 factor in the last line, and then use a simple table lookup to get the state from the day:

```
int table[ 14 ] = { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8 };
int state = table[ (int) (interval / secondsPerDay ) ];
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what you mean but after the first two weeks the state doesn't change and it remains on the last known state (week 2, day 0).

Comment: So rather than doing the table lookup as shown, first check to see whether the quotient is greater than 13; if it is, set it to 14, and then do the table lookup (with a 14th element in the table, with value 9).

Comment: Ahh I see! Wow thanks for your help. Much nicer code - is there a way for me to test this out without having to wait days?

Comment: Well you can change the values of firstDate and secondDate artificially by building it from components.